# error with interface writable in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, writable

I have create a class VectorWritable which implements the interface Writable. I am trying to write a VectorWritable object to the output file but i am getting this: VectorWritable@1355b88b. Here is my write method:

```
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {  
   getVectorString().write(out);
}
```

The function getVectorString() gives a Text object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have 50 rep to comment, so I will write it as an answer.

How do you create this Text object inside getVectorString()? Aren't you invoking default toString() method on the VectorWritable object, which returns strings like "VectorWritable@1355b88b" unless you override it to return a more useful string which describes your object?

EDIT:

According to your comment `Text vectorString` is a member of `VectorWritable` class, you set this `Text` object in `set` method so i guess that the `set` method is also inside `VectorWritable`, and it is not a static method, so why do you pass a `VectorWritable` object to it? It looks like you could invoke this `set` method on one `VectorWritable` object, pass another to it, and have `vectorString` not matching surrounding `VectorWritable` object.

How do you write `VectorWritable` to the output? Do you invoke the `write` method which you posted inside your question? Because this output `VectorWritable@1355b88b` looks like you pass `VectorWritable` as an argument to a method which invokes its default `toString()` method which would return string like `VectorWritable@1355b88b`.

Writable interface is used to serialize objects. So you can write the object to an output, and read it back, but with your implementation it would be hard to parse the string you create and read the object back. [Example of implementation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable.html)

```
   public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
     out.writeInt(counter);
     out.writeLong(timestamp);
   }

   public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
     counter = in.readInt();
     timestamp = in.readLong();
   }
```

Comment: In class VectorWritable i have these two fields:              private List<Double> vector = new ArrayList<Double>();
private Text vectorString; Before the method write i call the method set which is:                                          public void set(VectorWritable vectorW) {
  
  String temp = "";
  
  for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
   temp = temp + vectorW.vector.get(i);
  
  vectorString = new Text(temp);
 }

Comment: Yes the method set is inside VectorWritable class. I call the method set from my reducer class in order to set the result. After i call the method write (from my reducer class) in order to write the VectorWritable object. I 've tried the above but i had the same output.